# trying to pass cell.profilepic.image I get this error Thread 1: signal SIGABRT (Could not cast value of type 'UIButton' to 'UIImage')

Tags: swift, uibutton, uiimage, runtime-error, sigabrt

```
import UIKit
```

trying to pass cell.profilepic.image from ViewController2 to ViewController3

in runtime when I click on the Botton (func bottone) [my Botton is
    in the prototype cell of the tableView in viewController2]

I put the tableView func inside the botton's action cause I want that my pic3 (declared in ViewController3 as UIImage) is the pic I click in the TableView of my ViewController2

```
class ViewController2: UIViewController, UITableViewDataSource, UITableViewDelegate {

let images = ["image1", "image2", "image3"]

// here are my functions for the my TableViewCell2

func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
    return 1
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return (images.count)
}

// the identifier of my prototype cell in the TableView is cell (and nome is just a label)

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "cell", for: indexPath) as! TableViewCell2
    cell.nome.text = images [indexPath.row]
    cell.profilepic.image = UIImage(named: images[indexPath.row])
    return (cell)
}

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
}

override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

/* I put the tableView func inside the botton's action cause I want that my pic3 (declared in
ViewController3 as UIImage) is the pic I click in the TableView of my ViewController2 */

@IBAction func bottone(_ sender: Any) {
    func tableView2(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "cell", for: indexPath) as! TableViewCell2
        cell.nome.text = images [indexPath.row]
        cell.profilepic.image = UIImage(named: images[indexPath.row])
        performSegue(withIdentifier: "page3", sender: cell.profilepic.image)
        return (cell)
    }
}

override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
    if segue.identifier == "page3" {
        let viewCont: ViewController3 = segue.destination as! ViewController3
        viewCont.pic3 = sender as! UIImage
    }
}
}
```

Comment: What language is this code? I see syntax highlighting but I don't see a language tag.

Comment: @GeorgeKoehler swift

Comment: I should have guessed Swift. I feel dumb.